# How to fix "bower ENOTFOUND"

Tags: javascript, bower, bower-install

I'm trying to install https://github.com/catarse/catarse script on VPS(on my local machine works fine) and I have an error when I enter the command `bower install`:

```
bower checkout      catarse_admin#master
bower resolved      https://github.com/catarse/catarse_admin.git#3151581f33
bower ENOTFOUND     Package option not found
```

*bower.json*

```
{
  "name": "catarse",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/catarse/catarse",
  "description": "The first open source crowdfunding platform for creative projects in the world!",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "vendor/assets/components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "backbone": "~1.2.0",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "jquery-sticky": "~1.0.1",
    "jquery-smooth-scroll": "~1.5.5",
    "jquery-typewatch": "~2.2.1",
    "store": "~2.3.0",
    "jQuery-Mask-Plugin": "~1.11.4",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.4",
    "jquery-ujs": "~1.0.3",
    "jquery.fixedmask": "~1.0.0",
    "mithril": "~0.2.0",
    "catarse_admin": "https://github.com/catarse/catarse_admin.git#master"
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha! I made the same mistake ;)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

So shame.. I entered `bower install --allow-root option` instead of `bower install --allow-root`

Comment: Thx. I did the same mistake.

Comment: Totally did the same. Nice that this answer is here.

Comment: Hahaha, same here! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: jeez i did the same and i feel shame i came in here that fast without figuring out myself.

Comment: Copy paste driven development :-) Same here

Comment: oh nope same here thnx alot